# Swift: animation with CAGradientLayer skips/doesn't fade at end of animation?

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer

Alright, I'm having problems with my animated color gradient made in swift with CAGradientLayer-

The animation goes from these 2 color arrays here:

```
Self.gradient.colors = [colorWithHexString("#4342F9").CGColor, colorWithHexString("#A442F9").CGColor, UIColor.magentaColor().CGColor] //start
        self.toColors = [colorWithHexString("#FB22B5").CGColor, colorWithHexString("#FB258F").CGColor,colorWithHexString("#FD5E50").CGColor,colorWithHexString("#FD963C").CGColor] //end
```

And the gradient animation works well up until the animation is finished and it needs to loop. Here's the full animation :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        self.gradient.frame = self.view.bounds

        self.gradient.colors = [colorWithHexString("#4342F9").CGColor, colorWithHexString("#A442F9").CGColor, UIColor.magentaColor().CGColor] //start
        self.toColors = [colorWithHexString("#FB22B5").CGColor, colorWithHexString("#FB258F").CGColor,colorWithHexString("#FD5E50").CGColor,colorWithHexString("#FD963C").CGColor] //end

        //self.gradient.colors = [colorWithHexString("#6442F9").CGColor, colorWithHexString("#6442F9").CGColor]
        //self.toColors = [colorWithHexString("#FB863F").CGColor, colorWithHexString("#FB863F").CGColor]
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, atIndex: 0)

        animateLayer()
    }    

func animateLayer(){

        self.fromColors = self.gradient.colors
        self.gradient.colors = self.toColors! as! [AnyObject] // You missed this line
        var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
        animation.delegate = self
        animation.fromValue = fromColors
        animation.toValue = toColors
        animation.duration = 10.00
        animation.removedOnCompletion = true
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        animation.delegate = self

        self.gradient.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"animateGradient")
    }

    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {

        self.toColors = self.fromColors;
        self.fromColors = self.gradient.colors

        animateLayer()
    }
```

After it finishes cycling, the gradient "skips" meaning it doesn't fade from the darker gradient colors to the lighter toColors as it does the reverse direction. It just "flips".

Why is it doing this? How can I make it fade after it loops in animationDidStop?

Comment: I think the way CABasicAnimation does the interpolation it's either not performant going from few colors to more colors or it doesn't animate in those situations. Try your code but with the same number of color stops.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!